# Using jquery .each outside .getJSON method

Tags: jquery, each, getjson

I'm using a json api to create an array of data. For each item I want to create a html block to add to a list and append to a container. The following code works:

```
var url = "https://myjsonurl.json",

array = [],

html = "<ul class='card'>";

$.getJSON(url, function( res ) {
    array = res.badges;

    $.each(array, function(index, item) {
        html += "<li>HTMLblock</li>";
    });

    html += "</ul>";

    $("#reportCard").append(html);

});
```

However, the following code does not:

```
var url = "https://myjsonurl.json",

array = [],

html = "<ul class='card'>";

$.getJSON(url, function( res ) {
    array = res.badges;
});

$.each(array, function(index, item) {
    html += "<li>HTMLblock</li>";
});

html += "</ul>";

$("#reportCard").append(html);
```

This may be quite obvious but I can't understand why the last example will not work when the array and card variables are declared before the .getJSON call?

Comment: `https://myjsonurl.json` is no loaded and you are using it. simple.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. You're using the array before it has finished.

Comment: Is it not possible to save the response from the .getJSON call to a variable that can be accessed outside the callback function as I've tried to do in the second block of code?

Comment: It's certainly possible to use the variable outside the callback function. But it's not possible to use it *before* the callback has run, which is what you're trying to do.